# while loop function complexity with 2 variables

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, complexity-theory

the code is supposed to find the maximal drop (or difference) between 2 numbers while the bigger number must come before the smaller one (not necessaraly one next to the other).

I was wondering if you could help me out here to understand the complexity of the code.
What confuses me in this situation is, thinking of the worst case scenario ( correct me if I'm wrong please) I run through the array, n times for j and n-1 times for i.
is it added up or multiplied? and why?

O(n+n-1)? or O(n*(n-1))?

```
public static int maximalDrop (int[] a)
    {
        int max=0; int i=0; int j=1;
        while (j<a.length && i<a.length-1)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[j])
            {
                int temp = a[i] - a[j];
                if (temp > max)
                {
                    max = temp;
                }
            }
            j++;
            if (j>a.length-1)
            {
                i++;
                j=i+1;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: How many times do you think your loop gets executed? `n+n-1` times or `n*(n-1)` times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity of this code is `O(n * (n - 1) / 2)` or `O(n^2)`. The reasoning is simple, just consider the case where `n = 4`, then `(i, j)` values in the beginning of each iterations of while loop is as follows:

```
(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)
(1, 2), (1, 3)
(2, 3)
```

It can be seen that the complexity is `O(n * (n - 1) / 2)` as `i` is incremented only when `j` loops from `i + 1` to `a.length`.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of this code can be considered as 2 loops being nested, which is O(n^2)